# ¿Cómo realizar un Trigger que simule un campo secuencial dentro de tabla en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Estoy simulando el desarrollo de un sorteo con *MySQL*. El proceso consiste en el registro de participantes que posteriormente serán evaluados por un equipo de jueces. A cada participante deberá asignarse un equipo de jueces de manera proporcional para su posterior evaluación.

Actualmente tengo las tabla `participanteGeneral` y `juez`, que se comprende de los siguientes campos:

```
Tabla juez:

id_juez nombre_juez equipo
1        Jorge        1
2        Michelle     1
3        Edgar        2
4        Alejandra    2
5       Fernanda      3
6        Veronica     3

El campo id_juez es int(10) not null autoincrement.
El campo nombre_juez es varchar(30) not null.
El campo equipo es int(2) not null;
```

```
Tabla participanteGeneral:

id_par  nombre_par  equipo
1         Juan        1
2        Manuel       2
3        Diana        3
4        Miguel       1
5       Aurelio       2
6        Martha       3

El campo id_par es int(10) not null autoincrement.
El campo nombre_par es varchar(30) not null.
El campo equipo es int(2) default 0;
```

Estoy intentado realizar un *trigger* que me permita realizar lo siguiente:

- Obtener el valor del campo `equipo` del último registro de la tabla `participanteGeneral`.
- Verificar que el valor del campo `equipo` no sea mayor a `3`, si es mayor a `3`, reiniciarlo a `1`.
- Agregar el valor correspondiente al campo `equipo` del nuevo `insert`.

Probé lo siguiente, no me marcar error, sin embargo no se realiza el proceso:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `folioGeneral`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `folioGeneral`
AFTER INSERT ON `participanteGeneral`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE EQUIPO INTEGER;
    DECLARE NID INTEGER,
    SET NID = new.id_par-1;
    SELECT equipo INTO EQUIPO FROM participanteGeneral WHERE id_par=NID;
IF (EQUIPO = 3) THEN
       SET EQUIPO = 1;
      ELSE
       SET EQUIPO = EQUIPO + 1;
      END IF;
UPDATE participanteGeneral SET equipo = EQUIPO WHERE id_par = new.id_par;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hola José Manuel, te recomiendo que indiques con presición __de qué error hablas__. Edita tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía: [mcve].

Comment: Tu concepto de "último registro" parece sospechoso. ¿Puedes incluir ejemplos concretos con ejemplos de datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día a todos, encontré la solución a mi pregunta por si a alguien le es funcional:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `folioGeneral`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `folioGeneral` BEFORE INSERT ON `participanteGeneral`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE EQUIPON INTEGER;
    DECLARE NID INTEGER;
    SET NID = (SELECT id_par FROM participanteGeneral ORDER BY id_par DESC LIMIT 1);
    SET EQUIPON = (SELECT equipo FROM participanteGeneral WHERE id_par=NID);
    IF (EQUIPON = 3) THEN
        SET EQUIPON = 1;
    ELSE
        SET EQUIPON = EQUIPON + 1;
    END IF;
        IF (NEW.equipo = 0) THEN
        SET NEW.equipo = EQUIPON;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```